# Opening windows applications on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, macos, vmware

There's an application for windows only I was wondering if it was possible to run it on my MacBook 2008 on Yosemite. I have tried using VMWare fusion but it is too slow. Are there any faster alternatives? I also don't have any windows computer. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use BootCamp, but that would require you to buy Windows. The next best thing I can think of trying is [Wine](https://www.winehq.org), which can run (some) Windows programs on a Mac. To check if your program has been tested to work under Wine, check the [WineHQ app database](https://appdb.winehq.org). The database may not include a test of your program, so try running your program using [WineBottler (free)](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org) or [WineSkin (free)](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) which can repackage your Windows exe to a Mac app. Another you can try is [Crossover for Mac (Paid, offers Trial)](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/) that runs off of the same Wine backend. Hopefully one of those will work for you!